# Is it possible to create random object with same parent class without conditional statements?

Tags: java, class, oop, generics, constructor

For example,I have class A, A has child class B and C, I want to create A,B or C randomly,I can use conditional statements like that:

```
A a;
switch(new java.util.Random(3).nextInt()){
    case 0:
        a=new A();
        break;
    case 1:
        a=new B();
        break;
    case 2:
        a=new C();
        break;
}
a.doSomething();
```

but I want to have a better maintain version that is easy to add new child class, then I try to use array to hold a .class object for each Class, but it cannot compile because of "incompatible types":

```
Class[] array={A.class,B.class,C.class};
A a;
try{
    a=array[new java.util.Random(array.length).nextInt()].newInstance();
}catch(Exception e){
}
a.doSomething();
```

is there syntax to solve the problem above? If not, is there any generic way or syntax that can generate random child object without if-else condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using a wildcard. When generics are involved it's usually better to use `List` rather than an array. For example

```
List<Class<? extends Number>> list = Arrays.asList(Number.class, Double.class, Integer.class);
try {
    Number a=list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size())).newInstance();
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

This can be done with a `Class<? extends Number>[]` but there are problems with generic array creation.

Comment: This is the most typesafe answer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in java 8

```
    interface Sup extends Supplier<A>{}

    Sup[] sup = { A::new, B::new, C::new };

    A a = sup[rand].get();
```

Or, you could create a generic array

```
    Supplier<A>[] sup = array( A::new, B::new, C::new );


    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> T[] array(T... args){ return args; }
```

Comment: a `List<Supplier<A>>` would be better, as Boddington said.

Answer (score -1):

Try typing the array as Class<? Extends A>[] maybe?

If that don't work, the array of class names should work.

(edit) Dang, I forgot how hard it is to make arrays of generics.  In the past I've had to use Vector instead even when the size is fixed.

Comment: I get a `Can not create a generic array of type Class<? extends A>`.

Comment: not very hard, just make a vararg method:) `T[] array(T... args){ return args; }`